# Equivalence between $J = 0$ and $h = 0$ in Ising model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, magnetic-fields, ising-model, spin-models

This is the hamiltonian for the Ising-model in one dimension

$$H=-J \sum_{i=1}^N \sigma_i \sigma_{i+1}-h \sum_{i=1}^N \sigma_i$$

with $\sigma_i=\pm 1$ and $\sigma_{N+1}=\sigma_1$

$J$ is the interaction and $h$ the external magnetic field.
I convinced myself that I can write this with $J = 0$ and $h = 0$ as

$E_{N_{-}}=h\left[2 N_{-}-N\right]$ and $E_D=J[2 D-N]$ respectively.
$N_{-}$ is the number of negative spins and D is the number of connected spins that are the same.

Now I am wondering where this similarity comes from?

Comment: Is there some sign error here? The expression for $E_D$ is maximized for a ferromagnetic configuration with $D=N$ whereas your Hamiltonian suggests that should be the groundstate.